# How can I protect this exposed conductor at the panel?

Tags: electrical-panel

Noticed this cable with a conductor exposed along a ~5 inch length. I'm certain the visible conductor is the ground in this 14/2 as I carefully pulled apart the jacket to inspect it.  It looks like it was sliced more than needed to separate the conductors.

Is this something that needs to be addressed or can I leave it as is?

[image: panel cables]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely should be fixed, because otherwise the cable is open to additional damage.

Two options:

##### Electrical Tape

Give it a good wrap of electrical tape around the open part of the cable. Spiral along the entire problem area. As long as the only issue is the outer sheath, that will take care of it and prevent further damage.

##### Reposition Cable

- Find a lower available knockout on the side of the panel, low enough that the intact part of the cable can reach it.
- Turn off the breaker and remove the cable from the breaker, neutral and ground bars.
- Pull the cable out of the existing knockout.
- Move it to the new knockout with an appropriate clamp.
- Strip the cable sheath that is now inside the panel.
- If any of the wires have any nicks in their insulation, wrap with *matching color* electrical tape. If any of the wires appear seriously damaged, **STOP** and upload pictures for more help.
- If any wires (hot, neutral, ground) can't reach there previous locations or a suitable alternate (neutral can go on any neutral bar location, ground can go on any ground location or, if this is a true main panel, on any neutral bar location, hot must go to the same breaker but depending on the panel layout you may be able to move the breaker to a closer location) then extend with a matching color & size wire and a wire nut.
- Connect everything, turn on the breaker and test.

Obviously the second method is a *lot* more work than the first method, but the first method depends on verifying that the problem is **only** the sheath and no damaged insulation on any individual wires.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your instructions make repositioning the cable an approachable task but upon inspection the wires are in tact and electrical tape is the suitable route. Question, I have spare split loom cable tubing. Can I use that instead of tape? Or how about tape + tubing for added protection?

Comment: Use the tape. If you want to put something else around it, that should be OK.